# Scroll bar not scrolling for dynamic ASP generated div content

Tags: html, css, dynamic, scroll

My dilemma: I have a report div within the content div of page.  This report is dynamically generated in an ASP include file within the parent document and can vary in vertical height depending on the amount of information returned.  I have a style applied to the content and report divs, as shown below.  However, the report div does not scroll even though it overruns the content div (overflow-y will be set to auto once the scroll works).  I can fix it by setting a height in pixels on the report div, but that is not the desired behavior as most of the reports do not overflow the page and it needs to be versatile enough to resize the height based upon the browser window and display resolution.

The content div:

```
#content
{
z-index:1;
    height:auto;
width:610px;
    position:relative;
    top:86px;
    left:151px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:5px;
font-size:14px;
    text-align:left;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;
}
```

The report div:

```
#report
{
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border:solid 1px #000000;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

The block of code in the parent document (note that "reports" and "byType" are just named divs that are shown or hidden based upon user clicks):

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="reports" style="display:none;">
        <div id="report">
            <div id="byType" style="display:block;">
                <div class="reporttitle">
                    Incidents by Type
                </div>
                <!-- #include file="typeReport.asp" -->
            </div>
```

I've used up my fairly extensive CSS knowledge trying to figure this one out.  Is there maybe a display value I can apply to the report div that will accomplish what I want?  Please help!

Comment: Anyone?  I really need to get this working!

Comment: No one?  There has to be a solution to this.